# Fraction proportionality-linearity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

If  $$\frac {x_1}  {y_1} =\frac {x_2} {y_2}=\dotsb=\frac {x_n} {y_n}=k$$ Then
$$\frac {\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dotsb +\alpha_nx_n } {\alpha_1y_1 + \alpha_2y_2 + \dotsb + \alpha_ny_n}=k $$

Can someone explain why this is true. I ve heard that this can be proved with mathematical induction but that doesnt give a sense of understanding the result

Edit:Also if there are other ways of understanding this equality please post

Comment: This is nonsense  as stated. There must be additional information given about $x_n$ and $y_n$ that you're not telling us.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich x,y are any number, maybe i should have stated the question like if $\frac {x_1}  {y_1} =\frac {x_2} {y_2}=\dotsb$ then it follows$ \frac {\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dotsb +\alpha_nx_n } {\alpha_1y_1 + \alpha_2y_2 + \dotsb + \alpha_ny_n} $

Comment: Yes,, you should have stated it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x_j=ky_j$ and simpilify.

Comment: +1. Quite fine.

Comment: ??? How do you know that the same $k$ works for every $j$?

Comment: Because the ratios $x_j / y_j$ are all the same.

Comment: Right. How do you know the ratios are all the same? Or rather how _did_ you know? _As_ stated, $x_1/y_1=x_2/y_2$ is not a hypothesis, it's part of what we're asked to  prove...

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of *linearity*, i.e. if a fraction $f$ is a root of $n$ linear equations then it is a root of any linear combination of these equations.

$$\begin{align}
y_1 f = x_1\,&\Rightarrow\ \ \alpha_1 y_1\ f\ =\ \alpha_1 x_1\\
&\ \ \,\vdots\\
y_n f = x_n\,&\Rightarrow\ \  \alpha_n y_n\ f\ =\ \alpha_n x_n\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\phantom{I_{I_{I_I}}}\\
\hline
{\rm\color{#c00}{adding}}\,\  \!&\!\Rightarrow\! (\color{#c00}\Sigma \alpha_i y_i)f = \color{#c00}\Sigma \alpha_i x_i\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\phantom{I^{I^I}}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Answer (score 1):

Using induction.

For $n=1$: $\frac {x_1}  {y_1} =\frac {\alpha_1 x_1}{\alpha_1y_1}$ is true.

Assume it is true for $n=k$: 
$$\color{blue}{\frac {x_1}  {y_1} =\frac {x_2} {y_2}=\dotsb =\frac{x_k}{y_k}=\frac {\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dotsb +\alpha_kx_k } {\alpha_1y_1 + \alpha_2y_2 + \dotsb + \alpha_ky_k}}$$

Prove it for $n=k+1$:
$$\color{blue}{\frac {x_1}  {y_1} =\frac {x_2} {y_2}=\dotsb =\frac{x_k}{y_k}}=\frac{x_{k+1}}{y_{k+1}}= \\
\color{blue}{\frac {\overbrace{\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dotsb +\alpha_kx_k}^{a}}{\underbrace{\alpha_1y_1 + \alpha_2y_2 + \dotsb + \alpha_ky_k}_{b}}}
=\frac{\overbrace{\alpha_{k+1}x_{k+1}}^{c}}{\underbrace{{\alpha_{k+1}y_{k+1}}}_{d}}=\\
=\frac {\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2x_2+\dotsb +\alpha_kx_k +\alpha_{k+1}x_{k+1}} {\alpha_1y_1 + \alpha_2y_2 + \dotsb + \alpha_ky_k+a_{k+1}y_{k+1}},$$
because:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \iff \frac ab=\frac{a+c}{b+d}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe i didnt phrase myself in a best way possible in the question, i wanted to say that i am not interested in proof by induction

Comment: Seeing is better than hearing. In fact it all boils down to the first and last properties.